# How can the animation start over once one it stops?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a Traffic Light with HTML & CSS animation, but I don't know how can I make the animation to start over once the last one stop. I've tried with "animation: infinite;" but it's not possible. I know using JavaScript would be super easy to do, but I want to know if you have any idea of how to do it only using CSS.

Thanks!

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    :root {
        --cadetblue: #5F9EA0;
        --darkblue: #282845;
        --green: #14A014;
        --yellow: #FFD801;
        --red: #FF0A0A;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: var(--cadetblue);
    }
    
    .complete-section {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .traffic-body {
        width: 140px;
        height: 400px;
        border-radius: 120px;
        background-color: var(--darkblue);
    }
    
    .light {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .circle-red {
        animation: circlered 1s;
        background-color: grey;
    
    }
    
    .circle-yellow {
        animation: circleyellow 1s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    
    .circle-green {
        animation: circlegreen 1s;
        animation-delay: 2s;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    
    @keyframes circlered {
        from {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
        to {
            background-color: var(--red);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes circleyellow {
        from {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
        to {
            background-color: var(--yellow);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes circlegreen {
        from {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
        to {
            background-color: var(--green);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Traffic Lights</title>
    <html lang="EN">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="complete-section">
        <div class="traffic-body">
            <div class="light circle-red"></div>
            <div class="light circle-yellow"></div>
            <div class="light circle-green"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think what you really want is to restart the animation with a delay after it has stopped, is that correct? animation: infinite works, except it does not respect the animation-delay

Answer (score 0):

If you have `animation: infinite` then `animation-delay` won't be accounted for the only other way round is to account for the delay in `keyframes` itself.
In your case you have 3 lights and want to light them up one after another continuously then 3 period + you need to account 1 more period for delay hence you need to split your time in 4 frames one for each light i.e. 3 and one extra for delay. And voila you will get it.

You need to account for delay in `keyframes` itself if you are using `infinite` this is the way around.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --cadetblue: #5f9ea0;
    --darkblue: #282845;
    --green: #14a014;
    --yellow: #ffd801;
    --red: #ff0a0a;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: var(--cadetblue);
}

.complete-section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.traffic-body {
    width: 140px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    background-color: var(--darkblue);
}

.light {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.circle-red {
    animation: circlered 1s infinite;
    background-color: grey;
}

.circle-yellow {
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation: circleyellow 1s infinite;
    background-color: grey;
}

.circle-green {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    animation: circlegreen 1s infinite;
    background-color: grey;
}

@keyframes circlered {
    0%,
    25% {
        background-color: var(--red);
    }
    26%,
    100% {
        background-color: grey;
    }
}

@keyframes circleyellow {
    0%,
    25%,
    50%,
    100% {
        background-color: grey;
    }
    26%,
    50% {
        background-color: var(--yellow);
    }
}

@keyframes circlegreen {
    0%,
    50%,
    75%,
    100% {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    51%,
    75% {
        background-color: var(--green);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Fiddle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="complete-section">
            <div class="traffic-body">
                <div class="light circle-red"></div>
                <div class="light circle-yellow"></div>
                <div class="light circle-green"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/yh82nLaq/

HTML: (unchanged)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Traffic Lights</title>
    <html lang="EN">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="complete-section">
        <div class="traffic-body">
            <div class="light circle-red"></div>
            <div class="light circle-yellow"></div>
            <div class="light circle-green"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    :root {
        --cadetblue: #5F9EA0;
        --darkblue: #282845;
        --green: #14A014;
        --yellow: #FFD801;
        --red: #FF0A0A;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: var(--cadetblue);
    }
    
    .complete-section {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .traffic-body {
        width: 140px;
        height: 400px;
        border-radius: 120px;
        background-color: var(--darkblue);
    }
    
    .light {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .circle-red {
        animation: circlered 4s infinite;
        background-color: grey;
    
    }
    
    .circle-yellow {
        animation: circleyellow 4s infinite;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    
    .circle-green {
        animation: circlegreen 4s infinite;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    
    @keyframes circlered {
        10% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
        25% {
            background-color: var(--red);
        }
        
        35% {
            background-color: var(--red);
        }
        
        50% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes circleyellow {
        35% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
        50% {
            background-color: var(--yellow);
        }
        
        60% {
            background-color: var(--yellow);
        }
        
        75% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes circlegreen {
        60% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
        75% {
            background-color: var(--green);
        }
        
        85% {
            background-color: var(--green);
        }
        
        100% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    }
```

Explanation:

Here are the keyframes for the red light, with comments:

```
@keyframes circlered {
    /* Starts grey */

    /* Starts transitioning from grey to red 10% through, at 0.4 seconds */
    10% {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    /* Completes transition 25% through, 1 second into the loop */
    25% {
        background-color: var(--red);
    }

    /* Starts transitioning to grey, 1.4 seconds into the loop */
    35% {
        background-color: var(--red);
    }

    /* Is completely gray, 2 seconds into the loop */
    50% {
        background-color: grey;
    }
}
```

We have to bake the delays into the keyframes, because `animation-delay` only delays the *first* iteration, but we want to delay all of them. Unfortunately the stylesheet becomes more bloated.